# Bash - create multiple virtual guests in one loop

Tags: bash, virtualization

I'm working on a bash script (I just started learning bash) that involves creating virtual guests on a remote server. I do this by SSH'ing from server A to B and execute 2 different commands:

```
# create the images
$(ssh -n john@serverB.net "fallocate -l ${imgsize} /home/john/images/${imgname}")
```

and

```
# create the virtual machine
$(ssh -n john@serverB.net virt-install --bunch of options)
```

It is possible that these sets of commands have to be executed twice (if there need to be 2 virtual guests created) in a loop. When the second command is being run for the second time I sometimes get this error:

```
Domain installation still in progress.
```

This means I have to wait until the previous virtual guest is completed. How would I be able to do these operations in one loop? Can I run them asynchronously? Can I use threads? Or is there another way?

I have heard about the 'wait' command, but is that safe to use?

Comment: I believe that this does not really matter. 'Domain installation still in progress.' means that the installation has not been completed by the user yet. But i should be able to create virtual machine after virtual machine right?

Comment: The error message you are seeing is nothing to do with BASH and threading. Are you changing all the parameters required for VM creation such as name, disk etc. which are unique for each VM to a different value in the loop ?

Comment: @linuxmonk Yes, i get that information from the database, loop through the result set and create the VM's accordingly.

Comment: Can you re-phrase your question. Make it exactly about not being able to run virt-install while one is already running. Since this has nothing to do with BASH or threading. That way when people search they'll find what they are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check the man page for virt-install. You can use --wait=0 or --noautoconsole.

> --wait=WAIT Amount of time to wait (in minutes) for a VM to complete its install.  Without this option, virt-install will wait for the
>   console to close (not necessarily indicating the guest has shutdown),
>   or in the case of --noautoconsole, simply kick off the install and
>   exit. Any negative value will make virt-install wait indefinitely, a
>   value of 0 triggers the same results as noautoconsole. If the time
>   limit is exceeded, virt-install simply exits, leaving the virtual
>   machine in its current state.